# CTI (Class Table Inheritance)

Tags: mysql, multiple-inheritance

I'm working on an implementation of Multiple CTI on top of MySQL as a means to avoid implementing an alternative EAV for instance. Inheritance works fine and one table can inherit columns from one or several other tables, however several tables cannot inherit columns from single table. Do you know if such inheritance is possible at all based on this design pattern and if so can you advise on how to achieve it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After running a few tests and a some code modification, I was able to achieve the described inheritance in my question. One have to ensure that keys do not get duplicated across tables.
To recap, multiple tables CAN inherit from single table and that's valid. Hope it helps someone.